# Search module is returning 2 kinds of links, one to the k2 component and one a real url

Tags: search, joomla, k2

This is an old setup, and I'm not well-versed in K2. On our site we have two main categories. When I do a search, the resulting list shows two kinds of links. If it is Category 1, I get a full url like

```
http://oursite.com/index.php/category1/item/2113-wednesday-news-kick-off
```

If it is in Category 2, I get

```
http://oursite.com/index.php/component/k2/item/2120-necessary-inspections
```

The categories are exactly the same (same parameters and options selected) and they are both using the default layout. All the items are in K2 (none in Joomla Articles).

Both types of category items show in the menu as full urls, so ideally the search should return a full url for Category 2 items.

If you have any insight it would be greatly appreciated.